# is there jetty recipe example for cloudify 2.7

Tags: cloudify

Is there jetty recipe example for cloudify 2.7 ?

I want to use jetty to deploy my application,are there some example about it ?

I have searched in the [cloudify-recipes](https://github.com/CloudifySource/cloudify-recipes) at githup, but it does't contain jetty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a [Jetty recipe.](https://s3.amazonaws.com/public-examples/jetty_03_11_2014.zip)

I don't know if it works or not, but it can serve as a good start for you.

Good luck,

Tamir.